# Jenkins Docker Plugin does not seem to be provisioning slave containers for Jenkins builds

Tags: docker, jenkins

- Docker Host Metal OS - CentOS 7.3
- Jenkins Master running in a Container on the Docker Host Metal
- Jenkins 2.6
- Docker Host Metal listening on port 4243

I am not very familiar with the Jenkins [Docker Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin) and this might really be my issue. But right now my issue is that I am expecting the Docker Plugin to Spin up a Container on my Docker Host, I have configured my Docker Host as a Cloud in the Jenkins Configuration for Docker Plugin and Docker Plugin can connect to my Docker Host when I press "Test Connection":
[image]

I am using a very common Docker Image on Docker Hub as a Slave, not that really matters at this point because the Docker Plugin is not even trying to spin up a Docker container slave:[image]

Here is the configuration for my simple Jenkins job that runs, pulls source code and finishes without error, never spinning up a Slave Container at any point towork:
[image]
[image]

Here is the output of the Job running without error:
[image]

- **I have restarted Jenkins after installing Docker Plugin**
- **Docker is installed on my Jenkins Master Container**
- **Docker Plugin can talk to my Docker Host**

Here is my Jenkins Master Dockerfile

```
#reference
#https://engineering.riotgames.com/news/putting-jenkins-docker-container

FROM jenkins:2.46.3
MAINTAINER Brian Ogden

#setup folder for jenkins to log and save war file to
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y make apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg2 software-properties-common
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add -
RUN add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y docker-ce
RUN mkdir /var/log/jenkins
RUN mkdir /var/cache/jenkins
RUN chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/log/jenkins
RUN chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/cache/jenkins
RUN gpasswd -a jenkins docker
USER jenkins


#give Jenkins a nice 8 GB memory pool and room to handle garbage collection
#ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx8192m"
#give Jenkins a nice base pool of handlers and a cap
#ENV JENKINS_OPTS="--handlerCountStartup=100 --handlerCountMax=300"

ENV JENKINS_OPTS="--logfile=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war"
```

Here is a diagram of what I am trying to achieve ultimately:[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ok I figured it thanks to this [article](https://devopscube.com/docker-containers-as-build-slaves-jenkins/). As I suspected it was my Jenkins Docker Plugin Configuration settings.

First I had to give my slave Docker Template image a label:

[image]

Then I had to change my Jenkins Build project configuration to:[image]

Now Docker Plugin is provisioning a slave container on my Docker host